# Crashed: com.apple.main-thread EXC_BREAKPOINT

Tags: ios, swift, game-center, implicit-conversion

I am using the below function to find the number of pending turnbased matches(gamecernter-turnbased) in my iOS app.

```
var isPendingMatches = false
var numberOfPendingMatches = 0


func getTurnBasedMatches(){
        println("getTurnBasedMatches")
        GKTurnBasedMatch.loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler({(matches:[AnyObject]!,error:NSError!) -> Void in
            if(error != nil){
                println(error.description)
            } else{
//                self.numberOfPendingMatches = 0
                var pendingMatches = 0
                if let myMatches = matches {
                    for var i = 0; i < myMatches.count; i++ {
                        if(myMatches[i].status == GKTurnBasedMatchStatus.Open){
                            let part = myMatches[i].currentParticipant as GKTurnBasedParticipant
                            if(part.playerID == GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().playerID){
                                pendingMatches++
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(pendingMatches > 0){
                    self.isPendingMatches = true
                    println("pending turnbased matches in GC helper are \(pendingMatches)")
                    self.numberOfPendingMatches = pendingMatches
                }

            }

        })
}
```

I am getting this crash reports from crashlytics. I am not able to reproduce this crash and this is working perfectly fine on my device. I don't even know the exact line number where this crash is happening. But it looks like this is a Swift var issue. Can someone help me identify what might be causing this issue and how to resolve this.

```
    Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
    0  MY_APP                     0x000000010007650c MY_APP.GCHelper.(getTurnBasedMatches (MY_APP.GCHelper) -> () -> ()).(closure #1) (GCHelper.swift:437)
    1  MY_APP                     0x0000000100074d04 partial apply forwarder for reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@in (Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional>, Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional)) -> (@out ()) to @callee_owned (@owned Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional>, @owned Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional) -> (@unowned ()) with unmangled suffix "213" (GCHelper.swift)
    2  MY_APP                     0x00000001000765a8 reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@owned Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional>, @owned Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional) -> (@unowned ()) to @callee_unowned @objc_block (@unowned Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional, @unowned Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional) -> (@unowned ()) (GCHelper.swift)
    3  GameCenterFoundation           0x000000018f72e3a4 __39-[GKDispatchGroup notifyOnQueue:block:]_block_invoke43 + 28
    4  libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019856d994 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
    5  libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019856d954 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    6  libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019857220c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1608
    7  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001866af7f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
    8  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001866ad8a0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1492
    9  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001865d92d4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
    10 GraphicsServices               0x000000018fdef6fc GSEventRunModal + 168
    11 UIKit                          0x000000018b19efac UIApplicationMain + 1488
    12 MY_APP                     0x000000010006ac58 main (AppDelegate.swift:16)
    13 libdyld.dylib                  0x000000019859aa08 start + 4
```

The line number it shows in the report is the last closing line of getTurnBasedMatches function.